# How to get image width and height in OpenCV?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I want to get image width and height, how can I do that in OpenCV?

For example:

```
Mat src = imread("path_to_image");
cout << src.width;
```

Is that right?

Comment: Please be specific about languages. Because some things work in some but not in others.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You can use `rows` and `cols`:

```
cout << "Width : " << src.cols << endl;
cout << "Height: " << src.rows << endl;
```

or `size()`:

```
cout << "Width : " << src.size().width << endl;
cout << "Height: " << src.size().height << endl;
```

or `size`

```
cout << "Width : " << src.size[1] << endl;
cout << "Height: " << src.size[0] << endl;
```

Answer (score 104):

Also for openCV in python you can do:

```py
img = cv2.imread('myImage.jpg')
height, width, channels = img.shape
```

Comment: Good, but OP is asking for C++

Comment: Yes this is true but the google search for the python one brings you here.

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: @ArshdeepSingh make sure the image exists, the image path is correct, you are reading it properly, and the `img` object is of type `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. If the image path is incorrect and you try to use that in `cv2.imread`, it would give a WARNING not an error. Your program won't stop there!